# iOS Developer Programの自分のアカウントに不明なNameがある

Tags: xcode

XCode上で
　XCode -> Preferences... -> Accountタブを選択すると、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

という画面が出ます。赤枠の中のiOS,MacがFreeと書いた名前が見つかりますが、

(1) この名前は何でしょうか？勘違いかもしれませんが作った覚えがありません。
(2) XCodeのTeamでもこのNameを選ぶことができますが、何ができるものなのでしょう？

ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

アカウントを法人で取っていらっしゃいますか？
上が開発グループ(開発法人名)のアカウント
下が所属する個人のアカウントですね

AppleのMenverCenterにはアクセスしましたか？
YourAccountの項目で`DeveloperAccountSummary`があり、

```
Name(開発アカウント名)＝開発法人名
Agent(管理者)＝個人名
```

……になっているかと思います

Provisioningファイルを作る際に証明書を作らないといけないのですが
デバッグ用と申請用では作るアカウントが違います。
デバッグ用は個人(下の方)の名前で証明書を作ります
申請用は法人(上の方)の名前で証明書を作ります。

また、ストアに表示される開発元は上の名前(開発グループ・開発法人名)が表示されます。

Comment: おっしゃる通りアカウントを法人で取得しています。YourAccountの項目でDeveloperAccountSummaryでNameは確かに開発法人名ですが、Agentの記載がありません。またデバック用と申請用ではこのアカウントに紐付いているか紐付いていないかわかりませんが、developmentとProductionでそれぞれ証明書を作成しています。しかし、このNameの2つのアカウントには紐付いていないようです。また個人名のアカウントにはFreeとなっていますが、何か意味があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 個人アカウントには私もFreeと記述されております。これはアカウントの権限に何も制限がかかっていない事を示しています。ただ、DeveloperAccountSummaryにAgentの記載が無いと言う事はアカウントの役割(Role)が未設定の可能性が有ります。お一人で開発されている場合は必須ではありません。アカウントについては　https://developer.apple.com/support/account/jp/　Roleについての詳しい説明は　https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/jp/　を参照して下さい。